# understanding a proof of the hitting time theorem for a right-continuous random walk using generating functions

Tags: probability, random-walk

This is particularly directed at those who have Grimmett & Stirzaker, *Probability and random processes* (2005), at hand.
It pertains to the proof step prior to equation (10), p. 166.
For others:

- $X_i$ are i.i.d. integer-valued random variables with
  $\mathbb{P}(X_i \leq 1) = 1$ and $\mathbb{P}(X_i = 1) > 0$.
- $T_b=\min\{n:\sum_{i=1}^n X_i = b\}>0$ is the first hitting time of the point $b$.
- $G(z) = \mathbb{E}\left(z^{-X_1}\right)
   = \sum_{n=-\infty}^1 z^{-n} \mathbb{P}(X_1=n)$
- $F_b(z) = \mathbb{E}\left(z^{T_b}\right)
   = \sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n \mathbb{P}(T_b=n)$
- equation (9): $F_b(z) = F_1(z)^b$ for $b \geq 1$

---

I'm not understanding how to prove
$$
\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(z^{T_1}|X_1))
 = \mathbb{E}(z^{1+T_{1-X_1}})
 = z \mathbb{E}\left(F_{1-X_1}(z)\right)
 = z \mathbb{E}\left(F_1(z)^{1-X_1}\right)
 = z F_1(z)G(F_1(z))
$$

In J. G. Wendel, "Left-continuous random walk and the Lagrange expansion" (1975),
he argues in essence that
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(z^{T_1}|X_1))
 & = \sum_{n=-1}^\infty \mathbb{E}(z^{T_1}|X_1=-n)\ \mathbb{P}(X_1=-n) \\
 & = z \mathbb{P}(X_1=1) + \sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathbb{E}(z^{T_1}|X_1=-n)\ \mathbb{P}(X_1=-n)
 & T_1=1 \Leftrightarrow X_1=1 \\
 & = z \mathbb{P}(X_1=1) + \sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathbb{E}(z^{1+T_{1+n}})\ \mathbb{P}(X_1=-n)
 & \textrm{homogeneity} \\
 & = z \mathbb{P}(X_1=1) + z \sum_{n=0}^\infty F_{1+n}(z)\ \mathbb{P}(X_1=-n)
 & \textrm{definition of }F \\
 & = z \mathbb{P}(X_1=1) + z \sum_{n=0}^\infty F_1(z)^{1+n}\ \mathbb{P}(X_1=-n)
 & \textrm{equation (9)} \\
 & = z F_1(z) \sum_{n=-1}^\infty F_1(z)^n\ \mathbb{P}(X_1=-n) \\
 & = z F_1(z) G(F_1(z))
 & \textrm{definition of }G
\end{align*}
$$

In the second line, $n=-1$ is treated specially,
because the temporal and spatial homogeneity assumptions don't apply to it.
Specifically, the further time required to hit 1 is 0;
applying the homogeneity assumptions would imply $T_0=0$,
which isn't allowed, hitting times are positive.

In the fifth line, applying equation (9),
you can see that $n=-1$ needs to be treated specially there as well.

So although
$\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(z^{T_1}|X_1)) = z F_1(z)G(F_1(z))$,
it seems that Grimmett's intermediate steps are nonsensical.
Or can you see his logic?

---

Incidentally,
$$
\mathbb{E}\left(F_1(z)^{1-X_1}\right)
 = \sum_{n=0}^\infty F_1(z)^n\ \mathbb{P}(1-X_1=n)
 = \sum_{n=-1}^\infty F_1(z)^{1+n}\ \mathbb{P}(X_1=-n)
 = F_1(z)G(F_1(z))
$$
so the subsequent application of Lagrange's inversion formula on p. 166 is still done correctly.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, Mike. There is indeed potential for confusion over the definition of $T_0$. We need $T_0=0$ at this stage (but not earlier nor later), and we are adding a note in the next reprint.

Comment: @Geoffrey: Hello, and welcome to math.SE! I have converted your answer to a comment. Because you do not have 50 reputation points yet, [you are only able to comment on your own questions and answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work/19757#19757), so you were forced to post an answer; however, the "add comment" button will appear for you once you gain 50 points. Here is an [explanation of reputation points](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work/7238#7238).

Answer (score 1):

The key is that one defines $T_0=0$. Thus, $\mathrm E(z^{T_1}\mid X_1=1)=z$ is also $\mathrm E(z^{1+T_0})$ and, for every $k\leqslant0$, $\mathrm E(z^{T_1}\mid X_1=k)=\mathrm E(z^{1+T_{1-k}})$. Likewise, $F_0(z)=\mathrm E(z^{T_0})=1$, hence equation (9) holds for $b=0$ as well, and the computation of $\mathrm E(z^{T_1})$ which you recall becomes direct.

Comment: You can't define $T_0=0$. It has a meaning already: the time that the walk returns to the origin. I'll add Grimmett's definition above.

Comment: Nevertheless this is the (only) way to make true G&S computations. In other words, if one sets $T_0=\inf\{n\geqslant1\mid S_n=0\}$, the line you try to understand is false but if one sets $T_0=\inf\{n\geqslant0\mid S_n=0\}$, that is $T_0=0$, this line holds. (Here, $S_0=0$ and $S_n=X_1+\cdots+X_n$.)

Comment: By the way, you might wish to indicate where in the book G&S define $T_0$ in relation to equation (10) the way you say they do.

Comment: You raise a good point. Middle of p. 164, $T_r$ is defined. But $S_n$ is defined on p. 162, and there $n=0$ would be an element of the sequence $S$. But that confuses the definition of $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$. But in support of my interpretation of $T_0$, bottom of p. 162, "the random time $T_0$ until the particle makes its first return to the origin".

Comment: Then again, the definition of $T_0$ on p. 162 may be overridden by the one on p. 164. Hard to tell. It's all just a convention that needs clarification, and I've brought this post to Grimmett's attention.

Comment: Quite easy to tell, I would say. The answer is already there, just before your eyes. :-)